# edit Global.asax file and implement it in website

Tags: asp.net, .net, global-asax

I have website running which contains Global.asax file and App_global.asax.compiled also App_global.asax.dll but now i want to edit or add some existing code of url rewriting.
but when i do code in global.asax file it is not taking.

After lot of googling and search's i come to know i have to compile that global file again after changes done. but i cant do it as the websi## Heading ##te is live and i dont have the solution for it.

Existing code in Global.asax:

```
 protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpContext myContext=HttpContext.Current;

        Regex rewrite_regex = new Regex(@"(.+)\/((.+)\.*)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

       try
       {
              // 'see if we need to rewrite the URL
           Match match_rewrite =rewrite_regex.Match(myContext.Request.Path.ToString());

           string str = match_rewrite.Groups[2].Captures[0].ToString();
           string root = match_rewrite.Groups[0].Captures[0].ToString();
           if (Regex.Match(root, "/News/", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Success)
           {           
               myContext.RewritePath("~/Default2.aspx?nid="+str);
           }
           else if (Regex.Match(root, "/Search/", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Success)
           {
               myContext.RewritePath("~/Default.aspx?text=" + str);
           }
           else if (Regex.Match(root, "/Find/", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Success)
           {
               myContext.RewritePath("~/Default.aspx?text=" + str);
           }
```

Any help will be greatful.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't have the code the easier way will be to use the [IIS redirect rules?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module)
This will add the rules to your web.config. You can create multiple regex-based rules to satisfy your different conditions

e.g.

```
<rule name="Redirect from blog">
      <match url="^blog/([_0-9a-z-]+)/([0-9]+)" />
      <action type="Redirect" url="article/{R:2}/{R:1}" redirectType="Found" />
    </rule>
```